# How to handle large amount of data using linq in mvc

Tags: linq

I face a problem using a linq query. I am getting data from a SQL database using this query and `date time` parameter (see below). When this query executes, it takes a long time, and after a long wait, I get an error.

Data is available in database, and when I use `Take()` with number of rows, it will work. I don't to know how to figure out the problem.

Is it possible my query hits a large amount of data causing the query to not work? Can you please share any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

```
from ClassificationData in DbSet
where ClassificationData.CameraListId == id && 
      ClassificationData.DateTime <= endDate && 
      ClassificationData.DateTime >= startdate
orderby ClassificationData.Id descending
select ClassificationData
```

Comment: What amount of data are we talking about and where does the data come from (same server?)? Are you sure you want to retrieve all columns of _ClassificationData_? Consider specifying the columns in `select`.

Comment: Almost 20 lakh amount of data and comes from same server .Just i want data which lie in from or to dates .

Comment: What i need to do or any modification of query Let me know what is actual i facing the problems

Comment: 20 lakh is 2.000.000? That's a lot. What I meant by specifying the columns: Do you really need all columns of the table? Isn't it enought to just select a few of the columns? You would then have something like `...  select new { ClassificationData.Id, ClassificationData.DateTime } ...`

Comment: Yes 2,000,000 entries. I try to get specifying the columns which i need but i got same error "The wait operation timed out".

Comment: Then I don't really have another idea. Are you sure you need all the 2000000 entries? You could try to increase the timeout setting of the DataContext [DataContext.CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sometime I need to get 20K entries depend on date time but i face also same problem my querry takes long time.

Comment: try setting commandtimeout to 0...I recommend you DO NOT leave it there but that will see if SQL will return all of the data.  I would also suggest you start using some form of pagination as 2M records is a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably more in the realm of SQL than LINQ.  LINQ just translates what you write into Transact-SQL (T-SQL) that gets sent up to SQL Server. If your SQL Server is not set-up properly, then you'll get a timeout if the query takes too long.

You need to make sure that you have indexes on the ClassificationData table (I assume it's a table, but it could be a view --  whatever it is, you need to put indexes on it if it has lots of rows).  Make sure that an index is on DateTime, and that an index is also on CameraListId.  Then, bring down the data unordered and execute the order-by in a separate query done on the local machine -- that will let SQL Server start giving you data right away instead of sorting it first, reducing the chance for a timeout.

If your problems persist, write queries directly against SQL Server (in Query Analyzer, for instance, if they still use that -- I'm old school, but a bit rusty).  Once you have SQL Server actually working, then you should be able to write the LINQ that translates into that SQL.  But you could also make it a stored procedure, which has other benefits, but that's another story for another day.

Finally, if it's still too much data, break up your data into multiple tables, possibly by CameraListId, or perhaps a week at a time of data so the DateTime part of the query doesn't have as much to look through.

Good luck.